# How to drag an item from gridview and drop into another layout

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I have a grid-view and i set an adapter to that that contain array-list of image-views. I want to drag a single item from grid-view and dropping it into another layout. The problem I'm facing is how would i set a touch listener to a single item of grid-view so that i can drop it in target. If i am setting ontouchlistener in grid-view, it is picking whole grid view rather than a single item. Please help me...............
I've tried this code:

```
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOnItemClickListener());
        gridview.setOnDragListener(new MyOnDragListener());
        private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
         DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
         view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
         return true;
        } else {
        return false;
       }
       }
         final class MyOnDragListener implements OnDragListener{

    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable historyDrawer;
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        LocalLogger.LOGGER.info("Under on drag listener");
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            historyDrawer=v.getBackground();
            v.setBackground(enterShape);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setBackground(historyDrawer);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [OnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29) to find which child was long clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Add it in grid onclick like this -

```
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: startDrag method is available from api level 23 and above. So , this solution will not work for the most of devices at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only using `ACTION_DOWN` on your touch listener, you can use onItemClickListener  or onItemLongClickListener for your dragging.

```
grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int pos, long id) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    v);
            // start dragging the item touched
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to change imageview source of every grid item once whole gridview list is populated. So there is no point of onTouchlistener.

Comment: I edited my answer, if you need about onDrag part just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it next way:

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
     float currentXPosition = motionEvent.getX();
     float currentYPosition = motionEvent.getY();
     int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);
     View v = gridView.getChildAt(position);
     ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item("" + position); // here you send any data you want, I sent position
     String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML};
     ClipData data = new ClipData("" + position, mimeTypes, item);
     View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
     view.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
}
```